# Hide StatusBar for specific ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app where I want to hide the statusbar on a specific page. In my example it's a ContentPage. I found several samples where the info.plist is used to hide it, but I only want it for a specific page, is it possible? It's easy to hide the navigationbar with NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar, but statusbar seems a bit different.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I know, Xamarin doesn't provide this functionality through Xamarin.Forms classes. You will need to implement it in each platform specific project.

However, this should be fairly easy as you can use a [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to handle this.

Here is a quick implementation...

*App.cs*

```
public App()
{
    var layout = new StackLayout
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Children =
        {
            new Label
            {
                XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
            }
        }
    };

    var button = new Button
    {
        Text = "Click Me"
    };
    button.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        {
            if (_isHidden)
            {
                // show
                DependencyService.Get<IStatusBar>().ShowStatusBar();
            }
            else
            {
                // hide
                DependencyService.Get<IStatusBar>().HideStatusBar();
            }

            _isHidden = !_isHidden;
        };

    layout.Children.Add(button);

    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new ContentPage
    {
        Content = layout
    };
}
```

*IStatusBar.cs*

```
public interface IStatusBar
{
    void HideStatusBar();
    void ShowStatusBar();
}
```

*AndroidImplementation*

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarImplementation))]
namespace MyXamarinApp.Droid
{
    public class StatusBarImplementation : IStatusBar
    {
        public StatusBarImplementation()
        {
        }

        WindowManagerFlags _originalFlags;

        #region IStatusBar implementation

        public void HideStatusBar()
        {
            var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
            var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
            _originalFlags = attrs.Flags;
            attrs.Flags |= Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;
            activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
        }

        public void ShowStatusBar()
        {
            var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
            var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
            attrs.Flags = _originalFlags;
            activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

*iOSImplementation*

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarImplementation))]
namespace MyXamarinApp.iOS
{
    public class StatusBarImplementation : IStatusBar
    {
        public StatusBarImplementation()
        {
        }

        #region IStatusBar implementation

        public void HideStatusBar()
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = true;
        }

        public void ShowStatusBar()
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = false;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The idea being that you call the DependencyService implementation to hide the status bar when you need it hidden on a specific `ContentPage`. You also may need to show it again after hiding(not really sure).

NOTE: For iOS, you need to update the Info.plist file to allow the application to change the status bar visibility.

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: The implementation for android would be
public void Hide ()
  {
   
   var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
   activity.Window.ClearFlags (WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
  }

  public void Show ()
  {
   var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
   activity.Window.AddFlags (WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
  }

Comment: @RasmusChristensen I would make sure that works on all versions of Android that you need to support. I originally tried that on Android 4.1.1 and it didn't work. That's why I went with the code above.

Comment: You need the assembly attribute on the namespace level, not the class level. Just a minor detail. It works perfect

Comment: I removed the namespace all together for that purpose :)

Comment: It doesn't work on Android. The text of the status bar goes away, but the box stays there.

Comment: The follow minor change to obsolete API makes it work on Android.              var activity = Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity;
var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `PageRenderer` for this. Here is an example:

```
public class NoStatusBarPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public NoStatusBarPageRenderer()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(true, UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade);

        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(false, UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade);

        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
    }
}
```

Then, for each page that you want to have the status bar hidden, add an attribute to use this renderer on that page.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyContentPage), typeof(NoStatusBarPageRenderer))]
```

Comment: Actually it seems that doing it during a pagerenderer is the faster compared to DependecyService. Maybe because it happens before appearing and disappering

Answer (score -1):

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    ...
}
```

Comment: That would hide the status bar for all views in a Xamarin.Forms app(going by the Xamarin.Forms tag on the question), and only work on Android.