# How to hide status bar of splash screen in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am creating an xamarin forms app  where i need full screen for the splash page. How to hide the status bar only in splash screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you call status bar.

- If you mean the navigation bar :

As I can remember, there's a static helper `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(BindableObject, Boolean)`, it sets a value that indicates whether or not this NavigationPage element has a navigation bar.
Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar?view=xamarin-forms)

- If you mean the status bar (above the navigation bar) : 
  As I know, you will need to implement it in each platform, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36451267/1933150) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

In the page model of your SpashScreen page inside the constructor type this:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```